# What's the difference between "Export Data to file" and " Export with mysqldump" in IDEA?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

There are seems two ways to export MySQL data in IDEA: "Export Data to file" and " Export with mysqldump"

[image]

If I both choose insert and add table define(DDL) on "Export Data to file"

I can both get a .sql file after operation, so what' the difference between these two operation?

[image]
[image]

Comment: the `export with mysqldump` is using an external (to IDEA) tool, to export, see the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/export-data.html#create-a-full-data-dump-for-mysql-and-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a test table student and test it. In my finding:
The biggest difference between these two options is "Export Data to file" will generate insert statements one by one, and  "Export with mysqldump" will generate batch insert statements. So the latter have higher efficiency when import it.

[image: Export Data to file]

[image: Export with mysqldump]

Other differences:

- "Export with mysqldump" will include more metadata info, like
  `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`
- "Export with mysqldump" will include some comments about this export
  action, while "Export Data to file" have no comment.
- "Export with mysqldump" will show real MySQL command before it
  execute, like: `testDB --result-file="/Users/admin/student_dump.sql" --column-statistics=0 student --skip-add-locks --skip-lock-tables --add-drop-table`.  And "Export Data to file" will not, because it's a feature belong to IDEA, that make it possible to export to file in
  multiple types, like excel, CSV, JSON...

Comment: "Export with mysqldump" will generate batch insert statements.:  true by default, but you can specify the option `--skip-extended-insert` to have one record per insert.